# Нужно считать два числа из 2 текст боксов и вывести суму при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript

Не записывается значение в переменную а и б , не могу понять почему

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let a =document.querySelector('a');
        let b =document.querySelector('b');
        let sum;
        function check(){

                sum=parseInt('a')+parseInt('b');
                alert(a);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#d3d3d3">
<H1>Сума двох чисел</H1>
<form name="AUT">
<TABLE BORDER=1>
    <tr>
        <td class="a"><input type="text" name="pole"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="pole" id="b"></td>
        <td><input type="button" name="count" value="обчислити" onclick="check()"></td>
    </tr>
</TABLE>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: где класс 'а' написан   видите? а как из инпутов брать данные знаете? а что возвращает querySelector  читали?  а как выбрать элемент по классу изучали?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , Ничего не изучал , ничего не понимаю , ненавижу вообще этим заниматься , прошу помочь бездари , спасибо

Comment: изучите те 5 моментов, описанных выше, потому что сейчас это выглядит как код человека под горячкой

Comment: посмотрите в вопросы триединого пользователя dyc02210, Василь-Гнидка, olooliver - он с такой же домашкой пришёл

Comment: @nörbörnën , не знаю к чему эта информация

Comment: @nörbörnën , у меня нет второго аккаунта , вполне возможно что он с моего универа))

Comment: не, я вполне серьёзно и без наезда, там такая же задача, как у тебя, можно решение взять

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример, максимально приближенный к вашему

```
<input type="text" id="a" name="pole">
<input type="text" id="b" name="pole2">
<script type="text/javascript">
    let a = document.querySelector('#a');
    let b = document.querySelector('#b');
    let sum;
    function check(){
        sum = parseInt(a.value) + parseInt(b.value);
        alert(sum);
    }
</script>
```

Но, не советую его использовать, потому что как минимум нет проверок на введенные данные, во многих случаях результатом будет NaN (не число)

Comment: Спасибо , я так и написал , для меня достаточно , еще раз спасибо